# VIM replaces $1, $2, $3 and $4 with parantheses

Tags: vim

When I write a text in VIM (insert mode) it automatically replaces: `$1` with `()`, `$2` with `[]`, `$3` with `{}` and `$4` with:

```
{

}
```

For the other digits (E.g.: `$5`) it has an expected behavior.

How can I disable this replacement?

**Edit**:

1) If I type `$`, the caret remains about 1 second on that character. So, if I wait a little after typing `$`, it won't replace `$1` with anything.

2) Output for `:map $1` is:

```
v  $1          * <Esc>`>a)<Esc>`<i(<Esc>
```

3) Output for `:imap $1` is:

```
i  $1          * ()<Esc>i
```

4) Output for `:nmap $1` is:

```
No mapping found
```

5) I use many plugins, but according to the comments/answer, they are not relevant because there are some lines containing `inoremap` in my ~/.vimrc file.

**Details:**

- editor: VIM - Vi Improved 7.2
- O.S.: SUSE Linux

Comment: Vim doesn't do that by default; please tell us what plugins you use.

Comment: really? my vim doesn't do that. :-)

Comment: What does `:map $1` or `:imap $1` show?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is *not* the default behaviour of vim.

You probably have a map or an insert map for these keystrokes. You can verify this with a

```
:verbose map $1
```

or

```
:verbose nmap $1
```

which shows what mappings there are.

If this is indeed the case, the first place to look for definitions is in your `.vimrc`:

```
:e $MYVIMRC
```

then search for `$1` and/or `map` in the .vimrc

Alternatively, you might have some plugin that does that.

**Edited** with the helpful comment of *Marth* (using `verbose` to find out where the mapping was defined).

Comment: `:verbose map $1` might also help find out where the mapping was defined.

Comment: Thanks. There were some lines like `inoremap $1 ()<esc>i` in my ~/.vimrc file.

Comment: In my case it was "The Ultimate vimrc" plugin.  I fixed it by by removing the offending `vnoremap` and `inoremap` lines in `~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim`.